# Inquiry Regarding IAM Logging and Permission Analysis in GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, logging, permissions

I am currently studying IAM (Identity and Access Management) and am in the process of developing code to analyze user logs for each cloud service provider (CSP) with the goal of assigning minimum necessary permissions.

For AWS, I was able to extract the list of permissions used by a user by leveraging CloudTrail, which records all events performed by users. Based on these logs, I could specify a desired time range and extract the list of permissions used by a user during that period.

However, in GCP, despite enabling data read access for all services in Cloud Audit Logs, I encountered a challenge. Events such as SetIamPolicy or CreateRole, which involve changes in data, are logged. However, actions related to reading, such as checking the list of roles, are not captured in the logs. Consequently, I faced difficulty in extracting the list of permissions used by a user based on logs.

As an alternative, I explored the usage of the Recommender API's security statistics to extract the permissions used by a user. However, it appears that I cannot specify a time range for the data extraction, and it seems to retrieve all permissions used in the last 90 days. Is there a way to extract the list of permissions used during a specific period within the last 90 days?

Additionally, I would like to inquire about the timing when a new role assignment starts to be recorded in security statistics when assigning a user a new role. If a user is assigned a new role, from what point in time does this new role appear in the security statistics?

Moreover, I observed that there is no information in the security statistics for groups. Is it possible to extract the list of permissions used by users belonging to a specific group from the security statistics?

I am curious to know if reading actions are not logged by default in console logs or if there might have been an issue with my approach.

If it turns out that not all user events are logged, I would appreciate any guidance on alternative methods to extract the list of all permissions used by a user within a specified time range.

---

When I couldn't extract the list of permissions a user used from GCP logs, I wrote the following Python code as a workaround:

```
from google.cloud.recommender_v1 import RecommenderClient
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.api_core.exceptions import GoogleAPICallError
import json


with open('config/conf.json') as f:
    config_data = json.load(f)

KEY_FILE_PATH = config_data["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS2"]
PROJECT_ID = config_data["GCP_PROJECT_ID"]


def list_insights(project_id, location):
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(KEY_FILE_PATH)
    client = RecommenderClient(credentials=credentials)

    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/insightTypes/google.iam.policy.Insight"

    try:
        request = client.list_insights(parent=parent)

        for response in request.pages:
            for insight in response.insights:
                print("Insight name: ", insight.name)
                print("Insight description: ", insight.description)
                print("Insight content: ")
                for key, value in insight.content.items():
                    if key == "condition":
                        print(f"    {key}:")
                        for key2, value2 in value.items():
                            print(f"        {key2}: {value2}")
                    elif key == "inferredPermissions":
                        print(f"    {key}:")
                        for item in value:
                            for key3, value3 in item.items():
                                print(f"        {key3}: {value3}")
                    elif key == "exercisedPermissions":
                        print(f"    {key}:")
                        for item in value:
                            for key4, value4 in item.items():
                                print(f"        {key4}: {value4}")
                    else:
                        print(f"    {key}: {value}")
                print("Insight last refresh time: ", insight.last_refresh_time)
                print("Insight observation period: ", insight.observation_period)
                print("Insight state info: ", insight.state_info)
                print("Insight category: ", insight.category)
                print("Insight associated recommendations: ", insight.associated_recommendations)
                print("Insight target resources: ", insight.target_resources)
                print("Insight insight subtype: ", insight.insight_subtype)
                print("Insight etag: ", insight.etag)
                print("Insight severity: ", insight.severity)
    except GoogleAPICallError as e:
        print(f"Recommender API error: {e}")


project_id = PROJECT_ID
location = "global"

list_insights(project_id, location)
```

While this allowed me to obtain the list of permissions used by a user in the last 90 days, I encountered limitations. Specifically, I couldn't extract permissions for a specific time range. Additionally, when assigning a new role to a user, it took a considerable amount of time for the role to appear in the security statistics. I'm unsure about how to extract the list of permissions used by users belonging to a group. I'm seeking guidance on a method to extract the list of permissions used by a user within a specified time range in GCP.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Very interesting post but probably not a good one for Stack Overflow as you need new features. I recommend contacting Google Cloud directly and posting a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).